# How can I trigger a Jenkins build/job via an external Perl script?

Tags: perl, jenkins

I aiming to write a Perl script in a Unix environment which triggers a Jenkins build/job by passing the URL for the Jenkins master and other parameters.
How could this be done?

Here are some detailed questions I had:

- What Perl libraries would I need?
- What functions in Perl are needed?
- How can I pass other build parameters to Jenkins from the script?
- How do I get the results back from Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

You would normally need the [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP.pm) module and maybe its sub modules. [Here's an article](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html) on how you'd use it:

I am normally the person who will say "*Don't use `system` when you can use a Perl solution*".

However, I will make an exception in this case since it is way easier just to make that one system call to the [wget](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-UsingapostcommittriggerinCVS) command:

```
system qq(wget -q $build_trigger_url);
```

#### How can to pass other build parameters to Jenkins from the script?

To pass parameters to the Jenkins build will involve either setting environment variables by modifying the `%ENV` hash, or by modifying the URL to include these parameters (via a GET request). Different plugins and configurations require different ways of doing this.

If your build machine is a Windows system, you can download the [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) command.

#### How do I get the results back from Jenkins?

Jenkins has a built-in RESTful API. Just click the *REST API* links that are on the bottom of each page. You can use the [REST::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mcrawfor/REST-Client-249/lib/REST/Client.pm) module to make REST calls, but you can also just use `system` calls to `wget` too.

The RESTful API will return data in either JSON or XML format. You should get a JSON or XML module to help read this data. Sometimes, the RESTful API will return plain text like when getting the latest build number or timestamp.